# Normal Distribution Microsoft Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm trying to make a Macro in VBA to calculate normal distribution in MS Project. Does anyone know the proper command to do this?

Thanks in advance,

C.

I've tried to do this in different ways, even using the command for MS Excel but it doesn't work.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "calculate" here?

Comment: Always helps to show what you already tried, and explain exactly what happened when you tried it.

Comment: Normal distribution of what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.